# How to check if first character in a string is a bullet (Doesn't exist in ASCII)

Tags: c#

I want to check if the first character in a string in c# is a `•` how would I do this, since it has no ASCII value?

Comment: Step 1: Identify the Unicode codepoint you are looking for.  Step 2: Search for that codepoint,

Comment: This might help too: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: @StephenC I tried the unicode method, does not work. `\u2022` is the unicode character, attempted comparison to a bullet, always false.

Comment: The bullet is being read from a text file, if that changes anything

Comment: Then your problem is either that a different Unicode codepoint is being used as the "bullet", OR your code is not reading the text file the right way.  (Maybe there is a mismatch between the file encoding and the encoding your code uses / assumes when reading ....)

Comment: Maybe it's the `(char)0x2219` (Bullet Operator). Or the `(char)0x25CF` (● Black Circle). Anyway, where does this string content come from?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different unicode characters that might look like bullets.

1. Use https://unicodelookup.com to look up the code you're trying to match.
2. Specify the unicode character in C# using the [literal notation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx), such as: "\u2022" using the hex unicode for the character.

For example:

```
bool found = text.StartsWith("\u2022");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (inputString.First() == '•') Console.WriteLine("True.");
```

Comment: I ran it in LinqPad, with success. Did it just fail to detect the condition, or did it throw an exception?

Comment: failed condition

Comment: Looks like Peter has the solution. There are multiple bullet-like unicode characters. Once you find the right one (essentially, the right code), either method should work similarly.